# Mann Kendall test on raw time series or trend component?

Tags: time-series, trend

I have about 20 years worth of monthly data tracking an indicator. My goal is to determine whether the indicator is going up or down over those 20 years.

Mann Kendall tests seem like a good option since the trend isn't exactly linear and the test is non parametric.

However, I'm torn between running the Mann Kendall test on the raw monthly data or its trend component.

Your help is much appreciated!